# pin payment error - vendor/autoload.php not found

Tags: php, credit-card, omnipay

I have installed composer on my pc and running a pin payment script.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory;
$gateway = GatewayFactory::create('Pin');
$gateway->setSecretKey('1111111111');
$gateway->purchase(array(
    'email'       => 'abc.php2@gmail.com',
    'description' => 'Widgets',
    'amount'      => '49.99',
    'currency'    => 'USD',
    'card_token'  => $_REQUEST['card_token'],
    'ip_address'  => $_REQUEST['ip_address']
))->send();
```

I am not sure about **require_once _*DIR*_.'/vendor/autoload.php';** , where can i find the exact path for the same.

Comment: Do you have the directory `vendor`? If not you have to run `composer install` first.

Comment: i have installed composer but where do I find the vendor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think as you as "but where do I find the vendor" that **you did not run the `composer install` command.**

You have to run it in order to create the vendor dorectory and download the packages. Find out more **in the documentation**: http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-composer

Basically, run:

```
composer install
```